# How do I fix this error /usr/bin/ld: cannot find crtbeginS.o:

Tags: gcc, linker, fpga, ld

what cause this error aoc: Compiling for Emulation ....

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crtbeginS.o: No such file or directory

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s

aocl-clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0):

To fix the problem. You must give the crt file with it's absolute path. For the missing libraries, you can pass the path by using -L option.

Answer (score 0):

Symbolic link /usr/lib/libgcc.a -> /lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/libgcc.a
Replace 13 with whatever version you have.
Do the same for crtbeginS.o and all others it can't find.